# Access a Java method from JSP file placed on Tomcat server

Tags: java, jsp-tags, tomcat9, scriptlet

I've a use case to access a java method from a JSP file placed on Tomcat server.
I created a package "myCode" within webapps folder and placed both java source file "myJava" and jsp file "myJsp" inside it.
But when I've tried importing the file using <%@ page import="myCode.myJava"%>, I'm getting "The import myCode cannot be resolved". Anything missed from my side? Appreciate your help on this. Thanks

Expecting to call the java method from JSP file

Comment: How do you build your project?

Comment: What result do you expect from the java method? Do you need it to be called to get some data onto page context? Or respond to a user button click?

Comment: You don't import java source files. Your `import` statement could be correct, but your *class* file should be under WEB-INF/classes

Comment: Let me add some more context. I am developing a html page which contains a button. Upon clicking on the button, it should trigger the JSP which inturn should call the java method.

Comment: This doesn't work like that. JSP is a server side rendering, it already happened and finished when user clicks a button on HTML page. You need to make a network call from HTML page to server to execute some java code.

Comment: The idea is to place these html, jsp and java files on Tomcat server although not sure what should be the folder structure of this and where these files should be placed. Once placed and start the server, I should be able to access the html page which should trigger jsp and inturn call java method. PS: I am new to web development.

Comment: Can you give a quick glimpse on how its done?

Comment: This is too broad of a question. You need to read some books/guides on java web development basics... and looks like on java development in general.

Comment: You don't just "place jsp and java files on Tomcat", you need to deploy a web application in certain format. You need to get some idea about jsp, servlets and maven to begin with.